# Airflow telegram operator does not work due to Httpx

Tags: airflow, telegram, telegram-bot

I have used airflow telegram operator for notifying me on some metric after some task. Today I check the operator task fail with this exception:

```
TypeError: AsyncConnectionPool.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'socket_options'
```

Well I have researched some solution to downgrade httpx to 0.24.1 but python-telegram-lib does not fit with that

Answer (score 0):

Try installing an earlier version. I installed 3.1.1 and it worked

Answer (score -1):

On docker-compose.yaml:
With _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS : i add httpx==0.24.1
it work for me